# Struts 1: where to place properties file for message-resources

Tags: java, struts

I am getting a NullPointerError from struts, and the corresponding stack trace is the following:

```
PropertyMessa W org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources loadLocale   Resource org/apache/struts/action/ActionResources_en_US.properties Not Found.
PropertyMessa W org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources loadLocale   Resource org/apache/struts/action/ActionResources_en.properties Not Found.
RequestUtils  E org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils createActionForm Error creating form bean of class com.teig.territorymaint.web.TerritoryForm
at org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.createActionForm(FormBeanConfig.java:289)
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.createActionForm(RequestUtils.java:254)
at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.createActionForm(RequestUtils.java:208)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionForm(RequestProcessor.java:319)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:192)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
```

I don't understand why Struts is trying to fetch the properties file from the apache struts package path, and I suspected that my struts configuration is wrong:

```
<message-resources parameter="ApplicationResources" null="false" />
```

Then, I modified the message resources tag, and I got the same error:

```
<message-resources parameter="myPackagePath.ApplicationResources" null="false" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the complete stacktrace? The error is not necessarily caused by missing resources, it seems struts is not able to create an instance of your form class.

Comment: Do you have to use Struts? Can you switch to something that's not 10 years old and hacked out on an airplane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jörn is correct; the problem was not caused by the missing resource files, but my incorrect form-bean type attribute in struts configuration file

```
  <form-bean name="territoryAddForm"
         type="com.teig.territorymaint.web.forms.TerritoryForm">
         <!-- package path was incorrect -->
</form-bean>
```